# How to fopen() on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, c, file-io, filesystems

The iPhone SDK docs claim fopen() is a supported method of file access but I am unable to get it to return a FILE handle.  I am accessing a directory which is included in my project.  I have tried fopen "filename","dir/filename","./filename","./dir/filename","/dir/filename" all returning with a null pointer.  Some people report using it with no issue so I am sure it is something simple!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

if you're trying to access a file within your application bundle, you need to get the full path to it: `[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: FILENAME ofType: FILEEXTENSION]`

This returns an NSString, which you can pull a UTF8String out of and pass to fopen.

Answer (score 23):

Just to be clear to open a file "some.txt"...

```
NSString * path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:  @"some" ofType: @"txt"];
FILE *f = fopen([path cStringUsingEncoding:1],"r");
if (f == NULL) NSLog([path stringByAppendingString:@" not found"]);
```

Comment: Nice answer, How to see the contents of audio after opening.

Comment: In stead of `[path cStringUsingEncoding:1]` you can also use `path.UTF8String`