# Loading data files in iPhone project

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

How does one read a data file in an iPhone project?  For example, lets say I have a static file called "level.dat" that is structured as follows:
obstacles: 10
time: 100
obstacle1: 10,20
...

I would like to read the contents of the file into a NSString then do the parsing.  How do I read the contents of a file into a string?  Also, where in the project should the "level.dat" file reside?  Should it be under "Resources" or just in the main directory?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

See this answer: [How to fopen() on the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318341/how-to-fopen-on-the-iphone) which shows how to get access to resources in your bundle. Once you have the path, just use [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error:].

```
NSString   *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"level" ofType: @"dat"]
NSError    *error = nil;
NSString   *data = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile: path 
                                             encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding 
                                                error: &error];
```

Answer (score 3):

While this isn't what you asked for, consider turning your files into plists. You will have to reformat them into XML, but then you can load them straight into a NSDictionary with:

```
dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"levels" ofType:@"plist"]];
```

Comment: Note that you can do the same thing with arrays, it's very likely his data may be more suited to a top level of arrays rather than a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered putting the data in an SQLite database instead of a flat file?  I find that the API is very easy to use on the iPhone.

It is how I do all of my data storage on the phone now.

Answer (score -1):

If you need help parsing the data string, there's a helpful article on [Cocoa For Scientist](http://www.macresearch.org/cocoa_for_scientists_part_xvii_representing_data_in_tables)