# OCUnit - iOS 5 - How do I test files in my app?

Tags: iphone, ios, testing, ocunit

I am trying to build simple tests to see if files I need (images, videos, audio files) are in my app. Whenever I try to do something such as:

```
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:@"Menu Loop.mp3"])
{ 
    STFail(@"File does not exist");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Passed");
}
```

It says the file does not exist. I can see the file is there, and I know it is failing because the file in the app folder and not in the test folder. Is there a way of getting out of the test folder to test if the files exists without adding all of the files to the test folder? I have tried doing something such as fileExistsAtPath:@"../appfolder/Menu Loop.mp3" to try to navigate out of the test folder, but it unfortunately does not work that way either.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot directly access folders like that through the iOS SDK. You must save and read files using the system functions that return the proper path:

```
NSString *rootPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0]
NSString *pathToMenuLoopFile = [rootPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Menu Loop.mp3"];
```

If you are looking to load files that you include in your Xcode project, please take a look at this post: [Loading data files in iPhone project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321622/loading-data-files-in-iphone-project)