# UIImageView loads file on simulator but not on device?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview

This loads the image on the simulator but not on the device:

```
    UIImageView *splashImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"SplashPH.png"]];

[self.view addSubview:splashImage];
```

Any help appreciated // :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did not verify but you might want to use the `NSBundle pathForResource:ofType:` call - see [How to fopen() on the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318341/how-to-fopen-on-the-iphone)

Comment: Yup, that did it. Path issue. Thanks // :)